# How do I enable mTLS in mitmproxy for client to Proxy connection?

Tags: mitmproxy

There is client_certs option for mTLS between proxy and external websites but I don't see any option to enforce client authentication for the client connection to proxy.
Any help, pointers would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

mitmproxy does not support mutual TLS between client and proxy at the moment (version 8.1.1).